# Folder Monitoring using Powershell Not writing to a folder

Tags: powershell

I have set up the power shell script which is not currently writing to my outlog.txt file, can anyone see anything obvious? I am monitoring the C drive as it states in the first line.
Code:

```
  $folder = 'C:\Users\GeorgeH\Documents\Count' # Enter the root path you want to monitor.
  $filter = '*.*'  # You can enter a wildcard filter here.

  # In the following line, you can change 'IncludeSubdirectories to $true 
  if    required.                          
   $fsw = New-Object IO.FileSystemWatcher $folder, $filter -Property @
  {IncludeSubdirectories = $false;NotifyFilter =    
   [IO.NotifyFilters]'FileName, LastWrite'}

 # Here, all three events are registerd.  You need only subscribe to events 
 that you need:

 Register-ObjectEvent $fsw Created -SourceIdentifier FileCreated -Action {
 $name = $Event.SourceEventArgs.Name
 $changeType = $Event.SourceEventArgs.ChangeType
 $timeStamp = $Event.TimeGenerated
 Write-Host "The file '$name' was $changeType at $timeStamp" -fore green
 Out-File -FilePath C:\Users\GeorgeH\outlog.txt -Append -InputObject "The    
 file '$name' was $changeType at $timeStamp"}

  Register-ObjectEvent $fsw Changed -SourceIdentifier FileChanged -Action {
  $name = $Event.SourceEventArgs.Name
  $changeType = $Event.SourceEventArgs.ChangeType
  $timeStamp = $Event.TimeGenerated
  Write-Host "The file '$name' was $changeType at $timeStamp" -fore white
  Out-File -FilePath C:\Users\GeorgeH\Desktop\outlog.txt -Append -\
  InputObject "The file '$name' was $changeType at $timeStamp"}
```

Comment: If you write to a file that is in the folder you are monitoring wouldn't you create an infinite write loop?

Comment: How do you recommend I can alter my existing code? cheers

Comment: Also, you have a `\` at the end of a line? Do you intend that to be a line continuation character? Because that is not the line continuation character in powershell.

Comment: Which Line sorry?

Comment: Sorry, the comment escaped the backslash. You have a backslash charater at the end of a line ***Out-File -FilePath C:\Users\GeorgeH\Desktop\outlog.txt -Append -\*** the backtick character (grave) is the line continuation character in Powershell.

Comment: How could I amend?

Comment: Use a backtick instead of a backslash for a start. Also as I pointed out having the event write to a file that is in the folder that you are monitoring for changes is silly. That file will change...then write that it changed...which is a change...so write for that change...ad infinitum...